# The type initializer for 'Couchbase.CouchbaseClient' threw an exception

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I'm trying to create `CouchbaseClient` instance but i'm getting this error:

> The type initializer for 'Couchbase.CouchbaseClient' threw an exception

Everything has worked just fine before I put Couchbase dll in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Couchbase\v4.0_1.2.6.0__05e9c6b5a9ec94c2
```

And `Enyim.Caching.dll` in the old .NET 2.0 GAC.

Couchbase Console shows that the database is up and running.

Here is my app.config of the client tester:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="couchbase" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase"/>
  </configSections>    

  <couchbase>
    <servers bucket="default" bucketPassword="private">
      <add uri="http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default"/>
    </servers>
  </couchbase>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

What can I do in order to make this thing work ?

Note that the inner Exception is:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Couchbase' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Couchbase"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by changing the `App.Config` reference to Couchbase:

```xml
<configSections>    
  <section name="couchbase" type="Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase, Version=1.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=05e9c6b5a9ec94c2"/>
</configSections>
```

I needed to reference the GAC